# How to convert ascii char to byte in c#

Tags: c#, ascii

Hello I have a problem with conversion from ASCII to Byte. I have the code:

```
byte M = Convert.ToByte('M');
```

but this converts from UTF-16 to byte with I don't want. In my problem I would like to send bytes with ASCII codes.

Comment: use [System.Text.Encoding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.text.encoding(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: What exactly is the difference between a "byte with ASCII code" and a byte you get "from UTF-16" of an ASCII character?

Comment: @Corak `Convert.ToByte` has particular behaviors for different characters that aren't in the Unicode C0 Controls and Basic Latin block. If the question asker would say what's wanted in such cases, we could give guidance about how to achieve it. Or, perhaps the input is already known to be in the C0 Controls and Basic Latin block.

Answer (score 15):

just tell the compiler to convert the char to byte:

```
 byte b = (byte)'M';
```

or  (see comment of Adwaenyth above)

```
byte b = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("M")[0];
```

b will have the value 77 (ASCII for M).

Or for a string:

```
byte[] b2 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("text");
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not use `int a = 'm';` It converts the `m` into its ascii equivalent. You could then use it as you wish.

Comment: Chars in .Net are still Unicode which takes 2 bytes. It doesn't *convert* it to ASCII, it just shows the 2-byte representation of the char('m')