# How to Get ascii code of special character in C#

Tags: c#, ascii

I want to get the ascii code of the special characters of this example "º" and the result should be 186 but my code gives me 63 please help me.

Here is my Code:

```
string prText ="º";
var tempVal = new byte[1];
byte[] Asc = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(prText);
foreach (byte z in Asc)
{
   tempVal[0] = z;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert ascii char to byte in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45637214/how-to-convert-ascii-char-to-byte-in-c-sharp)

Comment: i try this code and it gives me the special characters that i declare but i want to convert my special character into int "string pr = char.ConvertFromUtf32(186);"

Comment: Be aware that 186 is not ASCII. ASCII is a 7-bit encoding and its maximum value is 127.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The degree symbol is not representable as an ASCII character.   From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.asciiencoding.getbytes?view=netframework-4.8)

> ASCIIEncoding does not provide error detection. Any Unicode character greater than U+007F is translated to an ASCII question mark ("?").

You may want to use ANSI encoding with the Windows-1252 code page.  In this encoding, the degree symbol is represented as  0xBA (186).

Comment: Thank you.. I already solved my problem by doing this code "int int2 = Char.ConvertToUtf32(prText, 0)"

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using this code to get the correct value

```
string prText ="º";
int int2 = Char.ConvertToUtf32(prText, 0)
```

and result will be 186

Comment: https://theasciicode.com.ar/extended-ascii-code/box-drawings-double-vertical-line-character-ascii-code-186.html