# C# How i can convert " * " in byte

Tags: c#

Is this possible to convert `*` in byte?
I have a program where i need to use only byte and the problem is : all my command start by this character.
Thanks you for help !

Comment: ```Convert.ToByte('*')```

Comment: Thanks you, next time i will try obvious code before asking... Sorry.

Comment: You don't have to be sorry for not knowing something you're new to. Everyone started somewhere.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert ascii char to byte in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45637214/how-to-convert-ascii-char-to-byte-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe

```
byte myAwesomeByte = (byte)'*'
```